# Extracting a specific word using gsub and regex

Tags: regex, r, gsub

Leapfrogging from a previous question, I'm having problem with the proper reg expression syntax to isolate a specific word.

Given a data frame:

```
DL<-c("Dark_ark","Light-Lis","dark7","DK_dark","The_light","Lights","Lig_dark","D_Light")
Col1<-c(1,12,3,6,4,8,2,8)
DF<-data.frame(Col1)
row.names(DF)<-DL
```

I'm looking extract all of the "Dark" and "Light" (ignoring upper vs lower case) from the row names and make a second column containing only the string "Dark" or "Light"

```
Col2<-c("Dark","Light","dark","dark","light","Light","dark","Light")
DF$Col2<-Col2

          Col1  Col2
Dark_ark     1  Dark
Light-Lis   12 Light
dark7        3  dark
DK_dark      6  dark
The_light    4 light
Lights       8 Light
Lig_dark     2  dark
D_Light      8 Light
```

Ive changed the original data a bit to detail my current issue, but working of an excellent answer from Tyler Rinker, I used this:

```
DF$Col2<-gsub("[^dark|light]", "", row.names(DF), ignore.case = TRUE)
```

But the gsub gets tripped up on some of the letters in common. Searching the message boards for isolating an exact word with regex, it looks like the answer should be to use double slash with either

```
\\<light\\>
```

or

```
\\blight\\b
```

So why does the line

```
DF$Col2<-gsub("[^\\<dark\\>|\\<light\\>]", "", row.names(DF), ignore.case = TRUE)
```

Not pull the desired column above? Instead I get

```
          Col1    Col2
Dark_ark     1 Darkark
Light-Lis   12 LightLi
dark7        3    dark
DK_dark      6  DKdark
The_light    4 Thlight
Lights       8   Light
Lig_dark     2 Ligdark
D_Light      8  DLight
```

Comment: No one will answer a regex question if it isn't [ssce](http://sscce.org)

Comment: First, `\\b` is used for defining word boundaries. So you'll have to tell what's the exact string in between. You cant negate it afaiu. Second, it uses spaces and punctuations for finding boundaries... and `_` is not one of them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about this?

```
unlist(regmatches(rownames(DF), gregexpr("dark|light", rownames(DF), ignore.case=TRUE)))
# [1] "Dark"  "Light" "dark"  "dark"  "light" "Light" "dark"  "Light"
```

or

```
gsub(".*(dark|light).*$", "\\1", row.names(DF), ignore.case = TRUE)
# [1] "Dark"  "Light" "dark"  "dark"  "light" "Light" "dark"  "Light"
```

Comment: Though slightly risky in general practice, and due to `as.character` working the way it does, you could make the first one: `tolower(regmatches(rownames(DF), gregexpr("dark|light", rownames(DF), ignore.case=TRUE)))`

Comment: ....and arguably the second one would give more consistent results with: `gsub(".*(dark|light).*$", "\\1", tolower(row.names(DF)))`

Comment: @thelatemail, the output shown by OP has, for example, both "Dark" and "dark" depending on whichever is present in rownames. Hence the absence of `tolower` in the answer.

Comment: that's true, though it also says: "I'm looking extract all of the "Dark" and "Light" (ignoring upper vs lower case) from the row names and make a second column containing only the string "Dark" or "Light""

Comment: The first part of the sentence (upper vs lower) is for extracting, not for replacing. The second part of the sentence is conflicting with OP's output clearly. Anyways, wouldn't `tolower` give "dark" and "light" instead of "Dark" and "Light"?

Answer (score 5):

One option is to use `stringr` package:

```
library(stringr) 
str_extract(tolower(rownames(DF)),'dark|light')
[1] "dark"  "light" "dark"  "dark"  "light" "light" "dark"  "light"
```

Or better using @Arun suggestion:

```
str_extract(rownames(DF), ignore.case('dark|light'))
```

Comment: agstudy, seems you can do: `str_extract(rownames(DF), ignore.case('dark|light'))`